# How to calculate time difference in pandas data frame when the date time stamp is in rows and apply conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, api, trello

I have extracted data from trello card actions, all I have to do is find the total time when a card was being moved from To Do list to In Progress to Done to be reviewed. But the date is in rows not columns. Please help. I am stuck on it since 1 week.
Here is the sample of data:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TToT.png)

Comment: more info plz, show your df

Comment: your question is problematic because trello cards can switch back and forth between 'To Do', 'In Progress', and 'Completed'.

Comment: @hongsy yes trello cards can be moved from back and forth from the lists but I have to add up the time taken to complete the task.

Comment: do you have some working code that you can show us?

Comment: Can you get the content of the card in a format that can be pasted into a piece of code?